# Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
index.js

console.log("Hello World ")

//importing express from packages
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');
const adminRouter = require('./route/admin');
const userRouter = require('./route/user');

//importing from other files
const authRouter = require('./route/auth');
const productRouter = require('./route/product');

//INIT 
const  PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

const DB = ''''mongodb database url'''


//Middleware
//Client(flutter) -> middleware -> Server(Node) -> Client(flutter)
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(authRouter);
app.use(auth);
app.use(adminRouter);
app.use(productRouter);
app.use(userRouter);


//connction
mongoose.connect(DB).then(() => {
    console.log("connection successfull");
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e);
});



//CRUD -> Create Read Update and Delete
//creating api
//http://<yourapiadrress>/hello-world

app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", function(){
    console.log(`connected at port ${PORT}` );
})

app.post('/sahil', (req,res) => {
    console.log("sahil");
})
```

auth.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs')
const Users = require("../models/user");
const authRouter = express.Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");


authRouter.post("/api/signup", async function (req, res){
    
    try{
        //get data from client
        const { name, email, password } =  req.body;
        //post data in database
        console.log("hey ; ");
        const existingUser = await Users.findOne({ email : email });
        console.log("hey ; " + existingUser);

        if(existingUser){
            return res.status(400).json({msg : 'User with same email already exists!'}); 
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 8);
    
        let user = new User({
            name : name,
            email : email,
            password : hashedPassword,
        })
        /*
        {
        'name' : name,
        'email' : email,
        'password' : password,
        }
        */
    
        user = await user.save();
        res.json(user);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message});
    }
    
    //return that data to user
    // console.log(req.body);
})

 //Sign In Route
authRouter.post('/api/signin', async (req, res)=>{

    try{
        const{email, password} = req.body;

        const user = await User.findOne({ email })

        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({msg : 'User does not exist please create account to sign in'}); 
        }

        const isMatch = await bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password);

        if(!isMatch){
            return res.status(400).json({msg : 'Incorrect Password'}); 
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({id : user._id}, "passwordKey");
        res.json({token, ...user._doc })

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message});
        
    }

})

//validate User
authRouter.post('/tokenIsValid', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
        if(!token){
            return res.json(false); 
        }

        const verified = jwt.verify(token, 'passwordKey');

        if(!verified){
            return res.json(false);
        }

        const user = await User.findById(verified.id);

        if(!user){
            return res.json(false); 
        }
        return res.json(true); 

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error:e.message});
    }
})


//Get User data
authRouter.get("/", auth, async (req, res)=>{
    const user = await User.findById(req.user);

    res.json({...user._doc, token : req.token});
})

module.exports = authRouter;
```

product.js

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const {Product} = require('../models/product');
const productRouter = express.Router(); 


// /api/products?category=Essentials
productRouter.get('/api/products', auth, async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        console.log( req.query.category);
        const products = await Product.find({category : req.query.category});
        res.json(products);

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message });
    }
})

productRouter.get('/api/products/search/:name', auth, async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const products = await Product.find({
            name : {$regex: req.params.name, $options :  "i"}, 
        })
        res.json(products);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message });
    }

})

//Rating the product
productRouter.post('/api/rate-product', auth, async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const {id, rating} = req.body;
        let product = await Product.findById();
        
        for(let i = 0; i<product.rating.module;i++){
            if(product.rating[i].userId == req.user){
                product.rating.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }

        const ratingSchema = {
            userId : req.user,
            rating ,
        }

        product.rating.push(ratingSchema);
        product = product.save();

        res.json(products);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message });
    }

})


//get deal of the day
productRouter.get('api/deal-of-day', auth, async (req, res)=> {
    try{
        let product = await Product.find({});

        product = product.sort((product1, product2)=> {
            let product1Sum = 0;
            let product2Sum = 0;

            for(let i = 0; i<product1.rating.length(); i++){
                product1Sum+=product1.rating[i].rating;
            }

            for(let i = 0; i<product1.rating.length(); i++){
                product2Sum+=product1.rating[i].rating;
            }
            return product1Sum < product2Sum ? 1 : -1;
        })
        res.json(product[0]);

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message });

    }
})

module.exports = productRouter;
```

user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const userRouter = express.Router();
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const {Product} = require('../models/product');


userRouter.post("/api/add-to-cart",auth, async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const{id} = req.body;
        const product = await Product.findById(id);
        let user = await User.findById(req.user);
        if(user.cart.length == 0){
            user.cart.push({product, quantity : 1});
        }else{
            let isProductFound = false;
            for(let i = 0; i<user.cart.length; i++){
                if(user.cart[i].product._id.equals(product._id)){
                    isProductFound = true;
                }
            }

            if(isProductFound){
                let producttt = user.cart.find((productt) => productt.product._id.equals(product._id));
                producttt.quantity+=1;
            }else{
                user.cart.push({product, quantity:1});
            }
        }
        user = await user.save();
        req.json(user);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error: e.message })
    }
})

userRouter.delete("/api/remove-from-cart/:id",auth, async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const{id} = req.params;
        const product = await Product.findById(id);
        let user = await User.findById(req.user);
            for(let i = 0; i<user.cart.length; i++){
                if(user.cart[i].product._id.equals(product._id)){
                    if(user.cart[i].quantity == 1){
                        user.cart.splice(i, 1)
                    }else{
                        user.cart[i].quantity -= 1
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        user = await user.save();
        req.json(user);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error: e.message })
    }
})
module.exports = userRouter;
```

admin.js

```
const express = require('express');
const adminRouter = express.Router();
const admin = require('../middleware/admin');
const {Product} = require('../models/product');

//post products api
adminRouter.post("/admin/add-product",admin, async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const {name, description, images, quantity, price, category} = req.body;
        let product = new Product({
            name, 
            description, 
            images, 
            quantity, 
            price, 
            category,
        });
        product = await product.save();
        res.json(product);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error: e.message })
    }
})

//get products API
adminRouter.get('/admin/get-products', admin, async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const products = await Product.find();
        console.log(typeof(products[0]["price"]));
        res.json(products);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message });
    }

})

// Delete the product
adminRouter.get('/admin/delete-product', admin, async (req, res) => {
    try{

        const {id} = req.body;
        let product = await Product.findByIdAndDelete(id); 
        res.json(products);

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error : e.message });
    }
})

module.exports = adminRouter;
```

user model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { productSchema } = require('./product');
// const authRouter = require("../route/auth");
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);


const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        required : true,
        type : String,
        trim : true,
    },
    email: {
        required : true,
        type : String,
        trim : true,
        validate : {
            validator : (value)=>{
                const re =  /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
                return value.match(re);
            },
            message :'Please Enter a valid email address',
        }
    },
    password : {
        required : true,
        type : String,
        validate : {
            validator : (value)=>{
                return value.length>6;
            },
            message :'Please enter min 6 digit password',
        }

    },
    address : {
        type : String,
        default : '',
    },
    type : {
        type : String,
        default : "user",
    },

    cart : [
        {
            product : productSchema,
            quantity : {
                type : Number,
                required : true,
            }
        }
    ]
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

this was the error i am getting in console and

```
"error": "Users.findOne is not a function"
```

This was the error while fetching the url

I tried reinstalling mangoose but not solved the issue

Comment: infinite loop??

Comment: Hi! Please ***reduce*** the code in the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem that can easily be copied and pasted to see happen locally. Also: Module cycles are [covered by the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles), have you studied that and looked into why you have a cycle, what it means, and what you can do about it? What did you find out? What did you try?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the user model, change

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

to

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("User",usersSchema);
```

you still able to use your existing code, but it will be

```
User.User.fin...
```

because you were registered twice for the `User`

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: you need to change `const Users = require("../models/user");` -> `const { Users } = require("../models/user");` as you did for other models